# Pandas format cells containing list of float in Pandas DataFrame to_string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to use `float_format` argument from `Pandas.DataFrame.to_string()` to format within cell list of floats?

I have a Pandas data frame `df` with a column (`col3`) containing list of floats:

```
col1                    col2                                                        col3
   0      0.9999999350619099   [0.9999999350619099, 1e-12, 6.493808010308148e-08, 1e-12]
   1  5.8284650223352606e-08  [0.9999999417153463, 1e-12, 5.8284650223352606e-08, 1e-12]
   0      0.9999998660870891   [0.9999998660870891, 1e-12, 1.339129086538945e-07, 1e-12]
```

When running `df.to_string()`, I want to be able to format all floats (i.e. in `col2` and `col3`) like this for instance:

```
col1       col2                              col3
   0      1.000  [0.999, 1e-12, 6.493e-08, 1e-12]
   1  5.828e-08  [0.999, 1e-12, 5.828e-08, 1e-12]
   0      1.000  [0.999, 1e-12, 1.339e-07, 1e-12]
```

I tried by providing a custom function `float2string` (c.f. MWE below) to `Pandas.DataFrame.to_string()` argument `float_format` but it only formats `col2` which is a column of floats, and not `col3`.

**NWE:**

```py
from collections import Iterable
import pandas

# data
df = pandas.DataFrame({
    'col1': [0, 1, 0], 
    'col2': [0.9999999350619099, 5.8284650223352606e-08, 0.9999998660870891], 
    'col3': [
        [0.9999999350619099, 1e-12, 6.493808010308148e-08, 1e-12], 
        [0.9999999417153463, 1e-12, 5.8284650223352606e-08, 1e-12], 
        [0.9999998660870891, 1e-12, 1.339129086538945e-07, 1e-12]
    ]},
    index = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
)

# formating function
def float2string(input):
    """convert float to string for printing

    Input (float)
    Output (string)
    """
    if isinstance(input, Iterable):
        return list(map(float2string, input))
    else:
        if input is None:
            return None
        else:
            if float(input).is_integer():
                return "{}".format(input)
            if abs(input) < 1e-2 or abs(input) > 1e2:
                return "{:.2e}".format(input)
            else:
                return "{:.3f}".format(input)

# print
print(df.to_string(float_format = float2string))
```

and I get

```
    col1     col2                                                        col3
a1     0    1.000   [0.9999999350619099, 1e-12, 6.493808010308148e-08, 1e-12]
a2     1 5.83e-08  [0.9999999417153463, 1e-12, 5.8284650223352606e-08, 1e-12]
a3     0    1.000   [0.9999998660870891, 1e-12, 1.339129086538945e-07, 1e-12]
```

**SOLUTION**: thanks to @oskros answer below

```py
print(df.to_string(
    float_format = float2string,
    formatters = {'col3': float2string}
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you are making it more difficult for yourself if you have columns which are iterable objects themselves (lists, tuples, dicts, etc.) - is there any specific reason for having column 3 as a list of 3 objects, instead of splitting it into 3 separate columns?

But if you have a specific need to format the data this way, then you are almost there with your solution. Simply specify your custom function as a formatter

```py
print(df.to_string(formatters = [float2string, float2string, float2string]))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Initially I separated the columns but it was not smooth to reformat the data frame just for some debugging output, and then I reuse the elements of the column as lists, so I had to reformat the three columns into one.